# How to load controllers on my angularjs file in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, controller, mean-stack

I'm trying to load a controller content with its functions in my angular core file like this, in order to get the code separated and with more organization, but I receive this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at core.js:2
```

Here is my core.js file:

```
let app = angular.module('MainApp', []),
    mainController = require('./controllers/mainController.js');

app.controller('mainController', mainController);
```

And here is my mainController.js file:

```
module.exports = ($scope, $http) => {
    $scope.newElement = {};
    $scope.elements = {};
    $scope.selected = false;

$http.get('/api/elements').success(function(data) {
        $scope.elements = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

    $scope.registerElement = function() {

        $http.post('/api/elements', $scope.newElement)
        .success(function(data) {
                $scope.newElement = {};
                $scope.elements = data;
            })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };
}
```

Is there any way to load this content in the core.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `require` on client. If you want, use Browserify or Webpack.
`require` is a part of nodejs `lib/module.js`.
Check this styleguides
[John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) | [Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide)